# Populating FlaskForm from SQLAlchemy DB, returns an error:

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm debugging an error, when I try to query from my database to populate the fields of my FlaskForm, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    app = create_app(os.getenv('DVR_CONFIG') or 'default')
  File "C:\Users\---\myapp\\app\__init__.py", line 42, in create_app
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
  File "C:\Users\---\myapp\\app\main\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import views, errors
  File "C:\Users\---\myapp\\app\main\views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .forms import CharacterSelect
  File "C:\Users\---\myapp\\app\main\forms.py", line 15, in <module>
    class CharacterSelect(FlaskForm):
  File "C:\Users\---\myapp\\app\main\forms.py", line 17, in CharacterSelect
    user = User.query.filter_by(unique_name=session.get('unique_name')).first()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 500, in __get__
    return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py", line 78, in __call__
    return self.registry()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 990, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 771, in create_session
    return SignallingSession(self, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 153, in __init__
    self.app = app = db.get_app()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 922, in get_app
    raise RuntimeError('application not registered on db '
RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context
```

Here is the offending code:

```
from ..models import User

class CharacterSelect(FlaskForm):
    user = User.query.filter_by(unique_name=session.get('unique_name')).first()
    charId0 = user.characterId_0
    charId1 = user.characterId_1
    charId2 = user.characterId_2
    user_list = [charId0, 'Char0', charId1, 'Char1', charId2, 'Char2']
    new_user_list = [x for x in user_list if x is not None]
    selectedUser = SelectField(u'Character Select', choices=user_list)
```

From researching this error, it appears Flask doesn't know which app my DB is attached to. Also most of the stackoverflow answers I have seen recommend using:

```
with app.app_context():
    :
    :
    db.create_all()
```

However, from working through Miguels Flask Book and Flasky blog, he doesn't seem to need to use "with app.app_context()" and only uses "db.create_all()" in his unit test code. Miguel inits the DB like so:

```
def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)
    :
    :
db.init_app(app)
```

Any help in debugging and understanding this error is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has pointed me to the [FlaskForm Docs](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField), where the is a pretty sparse example.
Esentially I need to create the tuple list in my views.py and pass it into my Form Object, see below for details:

views.py:

```
    user = g.user
    charId0 = user.characterId_0
    charId1 = user.characterId_1
    charId2 = user.characterId_2
    user_list = [(charId0, 'Char0'), (charId1, 'Char1'), (charId2, 'Char2')]

    form = CharacterSelect(request.form)
    form.selectedUser.choices = user_list
```

forms.py:

```
class CharacterSelect(FlaskForm):
    selectedUser = SelectField(u'Character Select', choices=[])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    db.init_app(app)

    return app
```

Many things are nor clear from your code snippet. What is obvious however is that you have to have your `db.init_app(app)` inside your `create_app()` function. Then you would return `app` object from the function. Most preferably in different module i.e. `manage.py` (this really depends on your application structure)

```
from somewhere import create_app

app = create_app(config_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Now variable `app` is your application instance with `db` registered.

Comment: I do indeed have db.init_app(app) in my __init__.py file, so that explains that I have registered the database correctly with my app. I found some info from the FlaskForms doc's that pointed me in the right direction. Thanks for the input :)